# Angular 10: Karma Jasmine spied method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dom, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Is there any way that I can reset a spied method when it is spied like so:

```
it('unit test', () => {
    document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(document.createElement('div'));
    ....
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the original method at the beginning, then reset it after the test case finished.

E.g.

```js
  it('unit test', () => {
    const getElementById = document.getElementById;
    document.getElementById = jasmine
      .createSpy()
      .and.returnValue(document.createElement('div'));
    console.log(document.getElementById);
    document.getElementById = getElementById;
    console.log(document.getElementById);
  });
```

Logs:

```
LOG: function wrap() { ... }
Chrome 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 2 of 14 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.023 secs)
LOG: function getElementById() { ... }
Chrome 80.0.3987.87 (Mac OS 10.13.6): Executed 2 of 14 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.023 secs)
```

The first log prints the `getElementById` method wrapped by a spy.

The second log prints the original version.